# Auto-Ban justification

Tags: support, post-ban

In my past, I have not had the perfect question history. However, I have had questions that, for the most part, have been researched, had clear answers, and were specific. I was auto-question-banned a while ago, and didn't care too much due to lack of use of the service in the first place.

I have reviewed my questions since then, and believe that I have fixed most, if not all, of the original problems. All of my questions, save one, have either 0 or positive vote counts, but I am still banned. I do not receive many votes, due to asking on topics that were small at the time of asking.

I am still banned, and wish to be unbanned. If a ban removal is not possible, can I get some reasons for it to remain?

[Link to the question portion of my Stack Overflow Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1406409/grammer?tab=questions)

Comment: I think your case is unusual because you also actively answer questions. Most of the people who hit the question ban are just leeches.

Comment: The ban is automatic, so it will be removed once your past questions have been *improved* to the point of removing the ban.  (Improved is in italics simply because no one outside of the dev team really knows what is needed to improve your standing enough to release the ban)

Comment: But the first thing that comes to mind is deleted questions.  Did you get your deleted questions undeleted and fixed?  Deleted question supposedly count very heavily towards the question ban, so if you still have some, that could be what is holding you back from getting unbanned.

Comment: You had four deleted questions, three of which you removed yourself. I've undeleted these to give you an opportunity to edit them into shape. That by itself might put you over the threshold, but the questions do need a little work.

Comment: protip:  Don't tag something XYZ when your code says "StealXYZ" "ExploitXYZ" etc.  Makes the people who watch tag XYZ angry.

Comment: you can go as fast as you want on the Autoban

Comment: @Won't, that's the name of a popular script, that I use for a password recovery (on the official site, with devs watching it VERY close). I'll take that into account though. Thank you to all of you, as well

Comment: @psubsee2003, since you were the main factor behind the help I got, if you put those comments into an answer, I will upvote and accept it, as it was that information that got me to get past the ban (but I know I'm still on shaky ground)