# banned users - how to edit and improve asked questions

Tags: support, post-ban

I had asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968462/what-does-var-b-this-mean), which is similar to a previously asked question, and received negative votes. These downvotes pushed me under the limit and I was question-banned, about a year ago.

2 Days ago, I flagged the question for deletion, and the  Moderator declined, saying "Deletions HURT your account and will result in it being BLOCKED. I have undeleted all but one of your questions. EDIT AND IMPROVE THEM. Ask for help on Meta if you need advice on edits."

And here I am. What can I do to repeal this question ban?

Comment: We arent going to search through every one of your questions and give you recommendations. The moderator was asking you to put some effort in yourself, and ask for help on specific questions that you dont know how to improve.

Comment: The message merely indicates you should not delete content, but improve it if you can. If you can't, well, bad luck. But don't delete it. Looking at that particular question, I don't see how it can be improved, so just leave it alone.

Comment: I recently asked a VERY similar question here: (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166357/auto-ban-justification). The comments by `psubsee2003` really helped me, and you should take a look at them. They could help you out

Comment: If my answer helped you, accept it. It shows that the answer was helpful, and marks the question as "answered", to the scope of the asker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the question ban works:

It takes in several factors:

- Deleted questions (by community)
- Deleted questions (by moderators, weighted differently (I think))
- Net votes on questions
- Answers on questions
- Closed questions

and assigns an "overall" score for your question quality. If the score drops below a certain threshold, then the system denies you the privilege of asking questions, until you raise your score.

You can raise your score by editing your posts, having questions undeleted, and reopening them.

The easiest (and best) way to improve your posts is to edit them, and make them more SO friendly (If you need an example, look at [this question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10803936/revisions)). This was one of the main questions that got me question banned, and I was able to edit it and clarify to A) get it undeleted B) get it reopened C) get upvotes on it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my own experience, you can edit your previous posts to make them better and answer posted questions. I think it's critical. The more upvotes you get from your answers, the sooner your question ban will be lifted. Don't worry about when your question ban will be lifted because noone knows. Just focus on answering questions briefly and correctly. After gaining some upvotes, you can check by clicking on **[Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)** button to see if the ban was lifted or not. Good luck.