# How can I see the net vote changes over the history of a questions's edits?

Tags: support, voting

In a fit of outrage, responding to a system-generated "slap on the face", I posted an obviously [poor question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251677/237306) here on Meta SE. In the early stages of my attempt to rectify things, I have come across [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166824/237306) to an unrelated (or *indirectly* related) question. The answerer points to his/her own [question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10803936/revisions) as an example of how a poor question, after a series of edits, became a good one.

I have started studying said history but I don't get any sense on how the voting changed over time. I think that, on any given question (or answer), I can *only* ever see the *latest* net vote. Is it possible (I think not) or wouldn't it be useful to be able to see the snapshot vote tally corresponding to each edit?

(I have examined several of the suggested "Questions that may already have your answer" and the titles of the "Similar Questions" and think this is not a duplicate. I am, however, at your mercy.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing you are probably looking for is the question timeline - `{some-se-site}/posts/{post-id}/timeline`.

You can watch the timeline for, e.g. your "poor question" - https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/251677/timeline :)

Comment: Wow, that exists!?

Comment: @Tim [lies ;)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251796/how-can-i-see-the-number-of-up-down-votes-on-my-own-posts-without-1000-rep#comment822271_251796), you already know about it.

Comment: I thought he meant the reputation tab timeline: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/252153/tim?tab=reputation! Now i've learnt something twice!