# Viewing all history of post votes

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, up-votes

Is there a way to see the entire history of up and down votes of a post? That is, not only the current aggregate number of votes, but rather distribution of how many up votes and how many down votes.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251805/how-can-i-see-the-net-vote-changes-over-the-history-of-a-questionss-edits.

Comment: Isn't that just the 1k privilege?

Answer (score 9):

Every post has a hidden timeline to it, which has detailed info regarding the votes a post has aggregated each day, with links in the form of `http://[sitename].stackexchange.com/posts/[postID]/timeline`. (But obviously not the info about *who* voted)

For instance, the timeline link for this question is https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/290708/timeline.

You need the [established user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege to see the breakdown of votes though, and without it, you will only see the total score (upvotes−downvotes) for each day.

As animuson [points out in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290708/viewing-all-history-of-post-votes#comment943806_290710), it's only a sum of votes a post has gained each day, but it's the analysis with the most details about votes that you can get.

Comment: You don't need any privilege to view the timeline, but it should be noted that the timeline only gives you day-by-day summaries of votes. You can't see what time those votes actually came in from there.

Answer (score 5):

It is part of the [Established User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege.

You get this when you reach 1,000 reputation on launched sites - and when you get it, clicking on the score of a post you will see the breakdown.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/623997?postid=477816#graph) the votes table:

```sql
select creationdate
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) accept
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) upvote
     , sum(case when votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) downvote
from votes
where postid = ##postid##
group by creationdate
order by creationdate
```

You'll notice that you'll only get dates for the votes, not the exact time the vote was casted. This is done to ensure anonymity of voting

Keep in mind this data is refreshed weekly on sunday.

Comment: Just checking if you were still paying attention @Peter, you passed.  ;)   ... thanks.

Comment: I think the Stack Exchange Data Explorer should be called 'Dora'...